# React useState appears null

Tags: reactjs, null, use-state

I tried to refactor my class components into functional with hooks, but struggle with initial state declaration.

Code as follows:

```
export default function Profile(){ 
const [profile, setProfile] = React.useState({
 firstname: '',
 lastname: ''
})

 return (
  <SomeComponent value={profile.firstname} />
)

}
```

Error is "cannot read property 'firstname' of null"

console.log shows profile.firstname value, though

I do understand that somehow value is not there yet like with setState, but i don't know how to wait for it, then...
Because in class components initial state is, well, initialized actually, before render...

Actual values should be fetched over empty strings after, so it is not the case :/

Full code, i thought it's too much to copypaste:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import { 
  Container,
  Typography, 
  Paper, 
  Grid, 
  Avatar, 
  IconButton, 
  TextField, 
  Select, 
  InputLabel, 
  NativeSelect } from '@material-ui/core';
import { makeStyles } from '@material-ui/core/styles';
import { MuiPickersUtilsProvider, KeyboardDatePicker } from '@material-ui/pickers';
import DateFnsUtils from '@date-io/date-fns';
import Skeleton from '@material-ui/lab/Skeleton'
import jwt_decode from 'jwt-decode'
import { Redirect } from 'react-router-dom';
import { useHistory } from 'react-router';
import { 
  getProfile, 
  getProfileAvatar, 
  editProfile } from '../services/calls'
import UploadButton from './UploadButton'
import { 
  CheckCircleIcon,
  CancelIcon,
  EditIcon
  } from '@material-ui/icons';
import ProfileAvatar from '../components/ProfileAvatar'
import ProfileDataLine from '../components/ProfileDataLine'
import { AuthContext } from '../services/AuthContextProvider'
import { timestring, date_parse } from '../services/suppl'

const useStyles = makeStyles((theme) => ({
    root: {
      minHeight: 300,
      flexGrow: 1,
      minWidth: 300,
      transform: 'translateZ(0)',
      '@media all and (-ms-high-contrast: none)': {
        display: 'none'},

      },
    avatar:{
      width: "100px",
      height: "100px",
      'font-size': '1.5em'
    },
    paper: {
      marginTop: theme.spacing(5),
      padding: theme.spacing(3),
      display: 'flex',
      flexDirection: 'column',
      alignItems: 'center'
    },
    about: {
      flexDirection: 'column',
      alignItems: 'center'
    },
    edit: {
        'align-self': 'baseline',
        'max-width': 'fit-content',
        'min-width': 'fit-content'
    },
    profilecont: {
      alignItems: 'center',
      justifyContent: 'space-evenly',
    },
    error: {
        color: 'red',
        'font-size': '0.8em'
    },
    message: {
        color: 'green',
        'font-size': '0.8em'
    },
    debug: {
      position: 'fixed',
      top: '120px',
      left: '200px',
      'z-index': '10000',
      'font-size': '1em',
      padding: '0 0',
      margin: '0 0',
      '& > *': {
        'font-size': '0.5em',
        padding: '0 0',
        margin: '0 0'
      }
    }

}));


export default function Profile (props) {
    const classes = useStyles();
    const history = useHistory();
    const auth = React.useContext(AuthContext);
  const [profile, setProfile] = React.useState({
      firstname: '',
      lastname: '',
      id: auth.id,
      email: '',
      created: '',
      last_login: '',
      num_logins: '',
      groups_amount: 0,
      students_amount: 0,
      location: 'unknown',
      bday: '',
      pricing: '',
      rights: '' 
  });
    const [edit, setEdit] = React.useState(false);
    const [edited, setEdited] = React.useState(null);
    const [error, setError] = React.useState('');
    const [message, setMessage] = React.useState('');
    const [avatar, setAvatar] = React.useState('');
    const [disabled, setDisabled] = React.useState(false);

    const reloader = () => {
        setAvatar(this.state.avatar+Math.floor(Math.random()*(10**12)))
    }

    const profile_loader = () => {
        if (auth.loggedIn){
            const token = auth.accessToken
            getProfile(profile.id).then(res => {
                if (res && !res.error) {
                    setProfile({
                        ...profile,
                        firstname: res.firstname,
                        lastname: res.lastname,
                        email: res.email,
                        created: res.time_created,
                        last_login: res.last_login ? res.last_login : 'No logins yet',
                        num_logins: res.login_amounts,
                        groups_amount: res.groups_amount,
                        students_amount: res.students_amount,
                        location: res.location ? res.location : 'Unknown',
                        bday: res.bday ? date_parse(res.bday) : 'Unknown',
                        pricing: res.pricing,
                        rights: res.rights
                    })
                    setAvatar(res.avatar_url+Math.floor(Math.random()*(10**12)))
                }
                else{
                    history.push(`/users`)
                }
            })
        }
        else {
            history.push(`/`)
        }
    }

React.useEffect(() => {
    profile_loader()
  });

    const profile_edit = () => {
        if (auth.loggedIn){
            const token = auth.accessToken
            let user = {id: profile.id}
            const data = edited
            console.log(data)
            const keys = Object.keys(data)
            for (var i = keys.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
                user[keys[i]] = data[keys[i]]
            }
            editProfile(user).then(res => {
                if (res && !res.error) {
                    console.log(res)
                    setMessage('Profile info has been changed', profile_loader())
                }
                else {
                    setError(res.error, this.profile_loader())
                }
            })
        }
        else {
            history.push(`/`) 
        }
    }

    const editFields = () => {
        setEdit(true)
    }

    const onChange = e => {
    e.target.value === '' && !disabled && setDisabled(true); setError('fields cannot be emptied');
    e.target.value !== '' && disabled && setDisabled(false); setError('');
    setEdited({
        ...edited,
        [e.target.name]: e.target.value
    })
  }

    const onDateChange = date => {
    setEdited({
        ...edited,
        bday: date.toUTCString()
    })
  }

  const editFieldsApply = () => {
    setEdit(false)
    if(!edited){
      setMessage('Nothing changed', setTimeout(() => setMessage(''), 5000))
    }
    else{
      profile_edit()
      setTimeout(() => setMessage(''), 5000)
      setTimeout(() => setError(''), 5000)
    }
  }

  const editFieldsCancel = () => {
    setEdit(false)
    setEdited(null)
  }



    const pricing = (
      profile ?
      profile.pricing === 0 ? 'Demo' :
      profile.pricing === 1 ? 'Basic subscription' : 
      profile.pricing === 2 ? 'Premium subscription' :
      null
      : null
    );
    const rights = (
      profile ?
      profile.rights === 0 ? 'Student' :
      profile.rights === 1 ? 'Teacher' :
      profile.rights === 2 ? 'Administrator' : 
      profile.rights === 3 ? 'Superuser' :
      null
      : null
    );

    const now = new Date().getTime()/1000

    return (
profile && <Container component="main" maxWidth="md" spacing={2}>
            <Paper className={classes.paper}>
              <Typography component="h1" variant="h6" style={{ marginBottom: '25px' }}>
              Profile ID:{profile.id}
              </Typography>
                <Grid container spacing={2} className={classes.profilecont}>
                    <Grid item>
                      <Grid item md={true} sm={true} xs={true} >
                        <IconButton>
                            <ProfileAvatar id={profile.id} avatar={profile.avatar} w='100px' h='100px'/>
                            {profile.id == auth.id && <UploadButton reloader={() => {reloader()}} />}
                        </IconButton>
                      </Grid>
                    </Grid>
                    <Grid item className={classes.about}>
                        <ProfileDataLine editable label='First Name' onChange={onChange} edit={edit} purpose='firstname' value={profile.firstname} new_value={edited.firstname} />
                        <ProfileDataLine editable label='Last Name' onChange={onChange} edit={edit} purpose='lastname' value={profile.lastname} new_value={edited.lastname} />
                        <ProfileDataLine editable label='E-Mail' onChange={onChange} edit={edit} purpose='email' value={profile.email} new_value={edited.email} />
                        <ProfileDataLine label='Created' edit={edit} purpose='created' value={profile.created} />
                        <ProfileDataLine label='Last login' edit={edit} purpose='last_login' value={profile.last_login} />
                        <ProfileDataLine label='Num logins' edit={edit} purpose='num_logins' value={profile.num_logins} />
                        <ProfileDataLine label='Groups' edit={edit} purpose='groups_amount' value={profile.groups_amount} />
                        <ProfileDataLine label='Students' edit={edit} purpose='students_amount' value={profile.students_amount} />
                        <ProfileDataLine label='Location' edit={edit} purpose='location' value={profile.location} />
                        <Grid item md={true} sm={true} xs={true}>
                          {!edit
                          ? profile.bday instanceof Date && <Typography 
                          id="bday" 
                          name="bday" 
                          type="bday">
                            Birthday: {timestring(profile.bday).split(' ')[0]}
                          </Typography>
                          : <MuiPickersUtilsProvider utils={DateFnsUtils}>
                              <KeyboardDatePicker
                                margin="normal"
                                id="date-picker-dialog"
                                label="Choose date"
                                format="dd.MM.yyyy"
                                disableFuture
                                name='bday'
                                value={edited.bday != 'Unknown' ? edited.bday : new Date().toISOString().split(' ')[0]}
                                onChange={onDateChange}
                                KeyboardButtonProps={{
                                  'aria-label': 'change date',
                                }}
                              />
                            </MuiPickersUtilsProvider>
                          }
                        </Grid>
                        <ProfileDataLine editable picker edit={edit} new_value={edited.pricing} label='Billing plan' purpose='pricing' value={pricing}/>
                        <ProfileDataLine editable picker edit={edit} new_value={edited.rights} label='Rights' purpose='rights' value={rights}/>
                    </Grid>
                    <Grid item className={classes.edit} md={true} sm={true} xs={true}>
                                {auth.loggedIn & auth.exp > now && auth.id == profile.id
                                    && <div>
                                        {!edit
                                        ? <IconButton onClick={editFields}><EditIcon /></IconButton>
                                        : <div>
                                            <IconButton onClick={editFieldsApply} disabled={disabled}><CheckCircleIcon /></IconButton>
                                            <IconButton onClick={editFieldsCancel}><CancelIcon /></IconButton>
                                          </div>
                                        }
                                      </div>
                                }
                    </Grid>
                </Grid>          
              </Paper>
              <Grid container justify="center" style={{ marginTop: '5px' }}>
                 {error !== '' && <Typography className={classes.error}>{error}</Typography>}
                 {message !== '' && <Typography className={classes.message}>{message}</Typography>}
              </Grid>               
</Container>
    )

}
```

Comment: `value="profile.firstname"` is not valid syntax for what you're trying to do, and should not produce the error you describe. Does your actual code have `{}` brackets instead of `"`s, or what?

Comment: That looks better, but it still shouldn't produce the error, unless the `useState` call is different, or unless you're doing `setProfile` somewhere else not shown. Can you post the full code - ideally, copy-pasted, rather than typed in manually, which can introduce errors?

Comment: Oh, yes, sorry, that was a typo.

Comment: @CertainPerformance, thank you for your time.
I posted full code in edit, it is quite a lot hope it's readable...